# IP Whitelist Function - Flask - Python3.x

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I have created a web app which will be publicly facing. There are some admin tools that the IT department will use to administer certain things in databases for example.

I have all my routes and models for the database, I just want to get some insight as to whether my function would be a suitable method of whitelisting IP addresses to routes and if I have missed something.

```
def allowed_ip(request):
    if not request:
        now = time.strftime("%b-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(time.time()))
        app.logger.info('No request was sent -=- {}'.format(now))
        return False
    if request and request.headers['X-Real-IP']:
        if request.headers['X-Real-IP'] not in config.Config.ALLOWED_IPS:
            now = time.strftime("%b-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(time.time()))
            app.logger.info('Request received from non-whitelist client {} -=- {}'.format(request.headers['X-Real-IP'],
                                                                                          now))
            return False
        else:
            now = time.strftime("%b-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(time.time()))
            app.logger.info('Request received from whitelisted client {} -=- {}'.format(request.headers['X-Real-IP'],
                                                                                        now))
            return True
    else:
        now = time.strftime("%b-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(time.time()))
        app.logger.info('Request received from but no IP sent -=- {}'.format(now))
        return False
```

The function checks if it received a request, (I know that seems pointless but I was receiving some weird errors without this line), if it has received a request, it checks the X-Real-IP header to see if it in our whitelist.

Is there anything I'm missing that could be manipulated here?

I appreciate this may be a broad or off-topic question but I'm also open to other methods of doing this. Perhaps it would be better for me to manage whitelisting at Nginx's level?

My answer adapted into my code:

```
from functools import wraps
def whitelisted(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if request.headers['X-Real-IP'] not in app.config.get('ALLOWED_IPS'):
            return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

Now this is possible:

```
@app.route('/map')
@whitelisted
@login_required
def show_all():
```

Comment: Why not do the whitelisting in NGINX?

Comment: I'm fairly competent with Flask and Python. My Nginx knowledge stems from research and documentation and isn't as competent.

Comment: @OzzyWalsh please see my method above, doing it this way is a lot easier than editing my configuration in nginx using pycharm and it auto-reloads for me when I make changes and serves the new scripts. Otherwise I have to restart services by cli which takes some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will do something like this:

```
# helpers.py
from flask import request, current_app

def check_ip():
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            ip = request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', request.remote_addr)
            if ip:
                if ip in current_app.config.get('ALLOWED_IPS'):
                     return f(*args, **kwargs)
            return 'Nice try! <3' # Do a real thing like real http code for forbiden, etc ... use response

        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
    return decorator




# routes.py
index = Blueprint('index ', __name__)
@index.route('/')
@check_ip()
def hello_world():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

But just using the IP is not secure, if you want something better you should use flask_login or something like this in my opinion.

Comment: I already use Flask login for Users. What I'm trying to achieve is whitelisting up addresses for certain routes in the app. Does your answer still apply?

Comment: can you point me to documentation for writing custom decorators for flask? I like this thought of having `@whitelisted` instead of manually calling a function.

Comment: @Swift it's exactly what I did (look at check_ip, and then the example). If it's just whitelisting ips + login it's ok then.

Comment: It whitelists the /register /login and /ulm routes. Ok I will look at including this. Answer accepted as it does improve my code in a suggested way that's viable.